# c# How to determine if a file is in ClearCase

Tags: c#, add-in, clearcase

I am writing a program that needs to know whether a file (excel workbook) is in clearcase or not.  If so I need to check it out.
Here is my code for checking out a file:

```
    private void buttonClicked(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

        ClearCase.ClearTool checkingOut = new ClearCase.ClearTool();

        string fileLoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;

        checkingOut.CmdExec(@"checkout """ + fileLoc + @"""");
    }
```

I do not want to perform the checkout unless I know if it is in Clearcase or not.
This is part of an Excel add-in.

Thank You!

Comment: You can, following my solution of "cleartool ls", see if a file is checked out (look for a selection rule ended with `CHECKEDOUT`) or checked-in (no `CHECKEDOUT` at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to know if a file is in ClearCase is to perform a `cleartool ls aFile` (`ct.CmdExec("ls aFile");` with the CAL API)

See the [`cleartool ls` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm):

> List the VOB-resident objects and view-private objects in the current working directory.

```
cmd-context ls
Makefile@@/main/3                                   Rule: /main/LATEST
bug.report
cm_add.c@@/main/0                                    Rule: /main/LATEST
```

Here `bug.report` isn't in ClearCase yet: it has no selection rule associated to it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check whether a file in clearcase or not is to check whether file@@/main/0 exists

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ClearCase but [looking at the docs for the CLI](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_hood_cleartool_cli.htm) can you just execute the `find` command?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the ClearCase Automation Library for C# [ClearCase Automation Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/CAL.aspx)

On that page, it mentions this information:
[image]

After getting all the checked out files, you can search if the current file is a member of that list or not.

Comment: Do you know if I can also see if a file is checked in?