# Clearcase Element existence

Tags: clearcase

I want to check with a batch file if a certain element is already existent in Clearcase, or if I still have to add it.

How can I put this into a conditional statement?

Like:

```
if cleartool exists myFileName do myaction
else doOtherAction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a function which returns true or false depending on the element full name being part of the ClearCase view elements or not.
Then you can call that function from your `if... else...` statement.

Here are various commands that your function could use in order to determine if a file is a ClearCase element (meaning already added to source control) or not:

---

You can start by using the result of [cleartool ls -l](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm): if its output includes `view-private object`, it isn't added to source control yet.

```
cmd-context ls -long
version               Makefile@@\main\3      Rule: element * \main\LATEST
view private object   bug.report
version               cm_add.c@@\main\0      Rule: element * \main\LATEST
derived object (unshared)   hello@@2007-03-24T11:32.418
version               hello.h@@\main\CHECKEDOUT from \main\2  
                                              Rule: element * CHECKEDOUT
```

Here '`bug.report`' isn't added yet.
See more at "[About view-private objects](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/c_about_view_priv.htm)".
I already recommended that approach for a previous question using C#: "[c# How to determine if a file is in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6749719/6309)".

---

Another approach is to use `cleartool describe`, which would trigger an error if the element described is a private one.

---

As mentioned in the [technote "How to list view-private files in a view in Rational ClearCase"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21150095), the command [`cleartool lsprivate`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsprivate.htm) works only in dynamic views, not in snapshot views.
For snapshot view, you can use: `cleartool ls -r -view_only`

---

Another approach is to use [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm), as in "Clearcase: How do I check if an element has a version on the trunk that was created after I branched off from the trunk?"

Comment: My problem is not that I do not know how I can check this. I just do not know how to build my if else statement somehow

Comment: @ZerO you need first to build a function which, given the name of a file, will return true or false. Then you can call that function from your `if` `else` statement.

Comment: of course, but which function does return true or false? find or describe do not return a true or false value, that is my problem

Comment: @ZerO the function that *you* will write and which will determine if the file is added or not, using one the approaches I describe: `cleartool ls -l myFile|grep private` is a good start. It doesn't matter that those commands don't return true or false: all that matter is that they return something different when the element is or is not in source control, which allows your function to return true in the first case, false in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The following DOS batch file will add a file to ClearCase if it's not in there yet. Works in both dynamic and snapshot views.

```
@ECHO OFF
cleartool ls -l %1 | FIND "view private object"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 GOTO END
cleartool co -nc .
cleartool mkelem -nc -ci %1
cleartool ci -nc .
:END
```

You may want to add suitable comments instead of using the -nc switch.